# how to start or call an onCreate in android in the same way or manner of VB6's Form_Load

Tags: android, vb6, runnable, oncreate

my android app has let's say activity A and B. what i need is to start my activity B at startup without showing it and of course show activity A because it is the main activity.

here's my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "api-project-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    AlertDialogManager adm = new AlertDialogManager();
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public static String billName;
    public static String emailAdd;
    public static String accntNum;

    Button addDevice, showDevice, showDialog, register;
    Switch swiGCM;
    TextView txtRegStatusResult, txtBroadcastMsg;

    private String registrationStatus = "Not yet registered";
    private String broadcastMessage = "No broadcast message";

    String[] arrContentTxt;
    final Context ctx = this;
    int notifCount = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int contentTxtLength;
    Handler notifLauncher, notifStopper;
    String contentTxt;
    GlobalVariables gv = new GlobalVariables();
    int delay = gv.reminderDelay;
    int stopDelay = delay - (delay / 5);
    Handler hand;

    IntentFilter gcmFilter;

    //new set of variables for billCompute
    //for bill compute
    int totalWatt;
    int timerFirstRun;
    int totalHour = 1;
    double wattHourPerDay;
    double kiloWattPerDay;
    double kiloWattPerMonth;

    //bill
    int id;
    int watt;
    int stat;
    String name;

    //also for bill compute
    double billPerMonth;
    Double res;

    //global variables
    double costPerMonth = gv.costPerMonth;

    Handler handler;
    Handler adapter;

    //end new variables
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddDevice);
        showDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowDevice);
        showDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);
        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMainRegister);
        swiGCM = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchGCM);

        txtRegStatusResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        txtBroadcastMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBroadCastMsg);
        txtRegStatusResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);

        Log.d("Batelec", "initiating lblBillVal");
        //ListViewForm.lblBillVal.setText("");
        Log.d("Batelec", "initiated lblBillVal");
        Intent i = getIntent();
        billName = i.getStringExtra(billName);
        emailAdd = i.getStringExtra(emailAdd);
        accntNum = i.getStringExtra(accntNum);

        //for local notif 
        Resources res = getResources();
        arrContentTxt = res.getStringArray(R.array.notifContentText);

        contentTxtLength = arrContentTxt.length;
        Log.d("Batelec", "content txt length: "+contentTxtLength);

        Log.d("Batelec", "starting ListViewForm activity");
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewForm.class));

        showDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*DialogFragment diag = new SwitchCheckChange();
                diag.show(getFragmentManager(), "cbo Click");*/
                showNotif();
            }

        });

        gcmFilter = new IntentFilter();
        gcmFilter.addAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        useNotifLauncher();
        //useNotifStopper();
        //BillComputer.useHandler();

        swiGCM.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Batelec", "inside switch GCM");
                if(swiGCM.isChecked()){
                    connectToGCMServer();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    //connect to gcm
    public void connectToGCMServer(){
        //try{
            Log.d("Batelec", "start gcm client");
            //start gcm
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            Log.d("Batelec", "loaded connection detector");  
            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                adm.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to a working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                Log.d("Batelec", "not connecting to internet");
                return;
            }

            // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(ctx);
            Log.d("Batelec", "device checked");
            // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(ctx);
            Log.d("Batelec", "manifest checked");


            registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
            Log.d("Batelec", "registered receiver");
            // Get GCM registration id
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(ctx);
            Log.d("Batelec", "acquire registration id");


            try{
            // Check if regid already presents
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
                Log.d("Batelec", "registration id is null, registering device");
            }
            else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.              
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Batelec", "device already registered");
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                Log.d("Batelec", "registering again using AsyncTask");
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, billName, emailAdd, accntNum, regId);
                        Log.d("Batelec", "registering user to server");
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }//end gcm
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Batelec", "GCM Client Err: "+e);
        }

    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            txtRegStatusResult.append(newMessage + "\n");           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            //unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void registerClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    //start countdown for showing local notif
    public void useNotifLauncher(){
        notifLauncher = new Handler(){
             @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                  String string = bundle.getString("myKey");
                  Log.d("Batelec", "in handler string val: "+string);
                  try{
                      ListViewForm.lblBillVal.setText(string);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e){
                      Log.d("Batelec", "handler err: "+e);
                  }
                  gv.billVal = string;
                  Log.d("Batelec", "main gv.billVal: "+gv.billVal);
              }
        };
        notifLauncher.postDelayed(runNotif, delay);
    }

    public Runnable runNotif = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showNotif();
            billCompute();
            notifLauncher.postDelayed(runNotif, delay);
        }

    };

    public void useNotifStopper(){
        notifStopper = new Handler();
        notifStopper.postDelayed(stopNotif, stopDelay);
    }
    //destroy local notif
    public Runnable stopNotif = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            cancelNotification(x);
            notifStopper.postDelayed(stopNotif, stopDelay);
        }

    };

    // If the user changes the orientation of his phone, the current activity
        // is destroyed, and then re-created.  This means that our broadcast message
        // will get wiped out during re-orientation.
        // So, we save the broadcastmessage during an onSaveInstanceState()
        // event, which is called prior to the destruction of the activity.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putString("BroadcastMessage", broadcastMessage);

    }

    // When an activity is re-created, the os generates an onRestoreInstanceState()
    // event, passing it a bundle that contains any values that you may have put
    // in during onSaveInstanceState()
    // We can use this mechanism to re-display our last broadcast message.      
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        broadcastMessage = savedInstanceState.getString("BroadcastMessage");
        txtBroadcastMsg.setText(broadcastMessage);
    }


    // If our activity is paused, it is important to UN-register any
    // broadcast receivers.
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    // When an activity is resumed, be sure to register any
    // broadcast receivers with the appropriate intent
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, gcmFilter);

    }

    //add device button
    public void addClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddDeviceForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    //show device button
    public void showClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ListViewForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    //show local notif
    public void showNotif(){
        contentTxt = arrContentTxt[notifCount];
        Log.d("Batelec", "main notifCount: "+notifCount);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("notifCountNum", notifCount);


        Uri notifSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifReceiver.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, (int)(Math.random()*100), i, 0);

        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("MyPower Reminder")

            .setContentText(contentTxt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSound(notifSound)

            .addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi)
            .build();

        NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifMgr.notify(0, notif);

        notifCount++;
        if(notifCount == contentTxtLength){
            notifCount = 0;
        }
    }
    //destroy local notif
    public void cancelNotification(int notificationId){

        if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE!=null) {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
            nMgr.cancel(notificationId);
        }
    }

    public void billCompute(){

        TodoItemDatabase td = new TodoItemDatabase(ctx);
        Cursor cur = td.getActiveDevice();

        if(timerFirstRun == 0){
            timerFirstRun++;
            Log.d("batelec", "timer = 0");
        }
        else{
            try{
                if(cur != null){
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "1 hour elapsed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    for(int x = 1; x <= cur.getCount(); x++){
                        id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceName"));
                        watt = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceWattage"));
                        stat = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceStatus"));

                        totalWatt = totalWatt + watt;
                        Log.d("batelec", "id: " + id + " name: " + name + " watt: " + watt + " status: " + stat);
                        cur.moveToNext();
                    }
                    //totalWatt = 125;
                    Log.d("batelec", "total watt: "+totalWatt);

                    wattHourPerDay = totalWatt;//all active device wattage 
                    Log.d("batelec", "wattPerHour: "+wattHourPerDay+" (totalWatt)");

                    kiloWattPerDay = wattHourPerDay / 1000;//all device watts divided by 1000 watts = 1 kW
                    Log.d("batelec", "kilowatt per day: "+kiloWattPerDay+" (wattPerHour / 1000)");

                    kiloWattPerMonth = (wattHourPerDay * 30) / 1000;//watts per month
                    Log.d("batelec", "kiloWatt per month: "+kiloWattPerMonth+" ((wattPerHour * 30) / 1000)");

                    billPerMonth = kiloWattPerMonth * costPerMonth;//estimated bill per month
                    Log.d("batelec", "bill per month: "+billPerMonth+" (kiloWattPerMonth * costPerMonth)");


                    //Double res;
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                    res = Double.valueOf(df.format(billPerMonth));

                    Log.d("batelec", "new bill: "+res);
                    //ListViewForm.lblBillVal.setText(String.valueOf(res));

                    Message msg = notifLauncher.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Log.d("Batelec", "res val: "+String.valueOf(res));
                    bundle.putString("myKey", String.valueOf(res));
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    notifLauncher.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("batelec", "MainErr: "+e);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

as you can see i already used startActivity in my app. but as what i have said earlier, i just want to start activity B and not show it, like how we can call a Form_Load in VB6. if their is a way to hide activity B if it starts, can you teach me how in the most detailed way possible. i'll appreciate it

Comment: Since this is not a particularly common practice, perhaps you might wish to explain *why* you think you "need" this. Then, perhaps we can help you find a solution that fits Android better.

Comment: i really can't what you mean by "need". but it you are pertaining to the thing of me not wanting the activity to show up and just start it, then it is because the activity B is composed of a textview and a  list of device and wattage(listView) which is to be added by the user before the runnable can compute something. so there is no point, i guess, of showing an empty list to a user who don't know what it is for.

Comment: "i really can't what you mean by "need"" -- you are the one who used the term, in the second sentence of your question. Beyond that, you have still not explained why you "need" to start activity B at all, until whatever the user has done in activity A is completed.

Comment: sorry, i really forgets a lot of things when explaining something. well, if i don't start activity B when the runnable already needs to put the result of the computation in the activity B's  textview, android throws a NullPointerException because activity B is not yet started meaning the textview is still not yet created.